# How to use pgRouting together with Django?

Tags: qgis, postgis, pgrouting, django

I am using pgRouting together with QGIS. Now I want to convert everything into a web-solution. I decided to use Django for that. Creating the data-model and receiving geographical data from the database and showing the data in a leaflet map works perfect, but I can't get any information from the database, when I use my SQL-Query:

```
SELECT * FROM pgr_drivingdistance('SELECT id, source, target, traveltime_min as cost
FROM routing_dataset'::text, 1, 100000::double precision, false, false) di (seq, id1, id2, cost)
JOIN routing_dataset rd ON di.id2 = rd.id;
```

This Query works perfect using pgAdmin or QGIS. Using this in django with a "raw SQL Query" https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/sql/ does not work. I do not get an error, just nothing.

Is it possible, that "pgr_drivingdistance" is not usable within the django environment?